# Current track information for HLS livestreams

Tags: sonos

I noticed that my Sonos player can display current track info for PLS streams, but not for HLS streams. Is there a way to make it work for HLS streams too? What needs to happen on the broadcasting end and/or the SMAPI end to display current track info?

Comment: Since originally posting this I found [some relevant information](https://devdocs.sonos.com/docs/supported-audio-formats#embed-metadata-using-icecast2-or-id3v2). The stream was using ID3 v2.4.0 while Sonos supports ID3 v2.3.0.